# What is annotation for <task:annotation-driven> in spring 4.3

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm upgrading my app from spring 3.x to spring 4.3. And instead of xml configuration i'm want to java configuration(annotation). I unable to do configuration using annotation.

```
<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="8-25" queue-capacity="100" />
<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="10" />
<context:component-scan annotation-config="true" base-package="com.jobs"/> 
<task:annotation-driven executor="executor" scheduler="scheduler" />
```

Where and how to configure above configuration using annotation. 
And I want to apply above xml configuration to following MyClassName.java

```
<bean id="mcn" class="com.jobs.MyClassName">
    <property name="username" value="...."/>
    <property name="authorities">
        <list>
            <value>....</value>
        </list>
    </property>
 </bean>
```

I tried like following configuration using annotation but getting Exception:

```
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Properties 'authorities' and 'username' are required for bean 'myClassName'
```

MyClassName.java

```
@Component
public class MyClassName{

    @Value("CronUser")
    private String username;

    //@Value("#{'ROLE_SYSTEM'.split(',')}")
    @Value("#{'ROLE_SYSTEM'}")
    private List<String> authorities;

    @Required
    public
    void setUsername(final String aUsername)
    {
         username = aUsername;
    }

    @Required
    public
    void setAuthorities(final List<String> aAuthorities)
    {
        authorities = aAuthorities;
    }
  }
```

SprinQuartzJobConfig.java

```
package com.config;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler;

@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan({"com.jobs"})
public class SpringQuartzJobConfig {

@Bean
public Executor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(100);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(8-25);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}

@Bean
public Executor taskScheduler() {
    // set properties if required 
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    scheduler.setPoolSize(10);
    return scheduler;
}   
}
```

What is annotation for above xml configuration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `@EnableScheduling` and `@EnableAsync` respectively to replace `<task:annotation-driven>` scheduler and executor in the configuration class which would look something like below

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan({"com.jobs","com.my.package.second"})
public class DemoApplication {

    @Bean
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(100);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(75);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(50);
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    public Executor taskScheduler() {
        // set properties if required 
        return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    }   

    @Bean
    public MyClassName myClass() {
       MyClassName className = new MyClassName();
       // set properties
       return className;
    }
}
```

Refer docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-enable-annotation-support) for more details.

**EDIT** (*post error reported by OP*)

Couple of things regarding the `MyClassName`

- Replace `@Configuration' &`@ComponentScan`with`@Component` as it should be a spring bean and not configuration.
- Field `userName` does not require `@Autowired` as its value is supplied via `@Value`
- Field `authorities` too does not require `@Autowired`. However the syntax should be corrected as `@Value("#{'${ROLE_SYSTEM}'.split(',')}")` if `ROLE_SYSTEM` is defined in properties file as `ROLE_SYSTEM=foo,bar,alpha,delta`
- All occurrence of `@Required` should be removed as essentially all the `@Autowired` fields are mandatory by default unless specified otherwise via `@Autowired(required = false)`

Comment: Thank you for response. But where and what annotation I need to add for <context:component-scan annotation-config="true" base-package="com.jobs"/>

Comment: Do see the edit - `@ComponenetScan` need to be added on the configuration class which supports multiple package scan as well

Comment: means I need to create separate configuration class as DemoApplication class?

Comment: Not necessarily - there can be only one configuration class or you can have more. Although it's recommended to have different configuration class if application has too many configurations e.g. one with basic, other for security, datasource, web , transaction etc. which will help you keep them isolated and more maintainable.

Comment: I edited my question and followed your suggestion. But getting exception. Please check my question again. And tell me where i'm doing wrong.

Comment: I added thing which you are mention in answer. I'm not reading any value from properties file for private List<String> authorities; I want to put value statically. how I need to do?

Comment: it can be done as `@Value("#{'foo,bar,alpha,delta'.split(',')}")` which will yield four values in `authorities`

Comment: No luck. Still getting exception.

Comment: update the question with current setup; its likely few of the mentioned steps got skipped

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141713/discussion-between-bond-java-bond-and-anil-jagtap).